# Highlighting additional fields during custom validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have custom validation in my model very similar to this one:

[Multifield/range validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239895/multifield-range-validation)

and the solution offered just works:

```
errors.add(:base, 'Start date must be before stop date') if self.start > self.stop
```

Using `:base` causes just 1 error, and it's fine because I don't want two separate errors showing the same here. However, no fields are highlighted, and I need the `:start` and `:stop` fields highlighted too, as if I were using `:start` or `:stop` in `errors.add`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leverage Rails built in mechanisms: they consist in wrapping the form fields containing errors with a `div` with `field_with_error` class.

If this doesn't suit you:

- customize it, [see Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/39-customize-field-error)
- more manual solution, check which errors your instance bears and act accordingly, ie `@instance.errors.include? :filed_name`. In this scope, don't add all your errors to `base`

Comment: thank you, I will use JS to give a better look to validation using `field_with_error` classes.